# Assembly.LoadFrom behaviour different in Windows 7

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-7

For our application we use a messaging system where using the information in the message we can build various objects using reflection on the fly. A simplified version of this is:

```
if(Message.Control == "ControlA")
    Assembly.LoadFrom("ControlsA.dll")
else if (Message.Control == "ControlB")
    Aseembly.LoadFrom("ControlsB.dll")
```

Once we have the assembly we then invoke various methods as required.

The problem at the moment is that when we use this method for Windows 7 installations we receive a "Could not load file or assembly" error where the path that is reported as been searched is the users desktop directory where the application was launched from via a short cut (C:\Users\*user*\desktop).

My question is; why is the above method not looking in the Application Path for the DLLs in Windows 7 when it works in XP, should we be doing something differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

to get the path of the currently executing code? It should be easy to find your libraries when you have this info.

Comment: So do you suggest something like this? Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "ControlsA.dll")

Comment: Maybe Even GetEntryAssembly(), but that depends on your app

Comment: @MrEdmundo: exactly. yas4891's suggestion is also handy if mine is not good.

Comment: @yas4891 I'm happy to do that, I just thought from looking at the documentation for Assembly.LoadFrom that this took place anyway and it certainly does in XP.